# utl_http: ORA-24263: Certificate of the remote server does not match the target address

Tags: oracle, ssl, https, oracle12c

after upgrading our database system from 11g to 12c we cannot make https-requests to one of our webservers.
After a lot of googling and trial-and-error we are pretty sure that error is due to our remote certificate. The wallet doesn't contain the server certificate, only the CAs are present (read this somewhere, ora12 doesn't like the regular certs in the wallet any longer)

The only special thing I found about our certificate:

It has **no CN**, it has only a couple of SAN specified.

With 11g the requests work like a charm, but 12c doesn't allow the certificate any more. We found out that utl_http_request() got a new parameter, "https_host" which is matched against the **common name** of the server certificate ([1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/UTL_HTTP.htm#GUID-F2714239-C6B5-4F9A-86F3-1AA90B08106F__GUID-F0B6F471-4592-461B-9BC8-60E333C93FCE)), not saying anything about the subject alternative name. No matter which value we choose for this parameter, the call fails with an ORA-24263.

I cannot understand why oracle should ignore the SAN, as they are a pretty mandatory as per RFC6125 ([2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125)) from **2011**:

> However, it is perfectly acceptable for the subject field to be empty, as long as the certificate contains a subject alternative name ("subjectAltName") extension that includes at least one subjectAltName entry, because [...]

Anyone having similar problems?

How to work around this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Oracle Support as this is a known bug. I suspect Bug 25734963 : SNI SUPPORT IN UTL_HTTP
Note: There are a couple others such as Bug 26040483 and 26190856, but at least one will conflict so you may want to request a merge patch.